# AKMetronomeSampler delay

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, metronome

I'm making a metronome app and use `AKSamplerMetronome` class. I did synchronization between devices with Ableton link so they could play together. I start playing and after a while sound on the device starts to delay and after couple of minutes I can clearly hear it.

The thing is beat count synchronized correctly but the sound that comes from the phone is not.

This bug is not on all devices, on some of them it's working great, no delay.

for synchronization I call `setBeatTime` once on start

Any suggestions what it might be?

If I create instance of AKSamplerMetronome, wait for couple minutes and then play, sound immediately would be out of sync.

Comment: What's the difference between the devices it works on and the ones it doesn't? Is there a sample project you could share on GitHub?